# "Black Screen" on Android before the app is starting

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

Usually I don't ask for help in forums but after hours of trying to solve this problem and after hours of banging my head against the table I have to.

Actually I work with Cordova and build my apps with PGB. Generally my app works fine and my animations are clean and free of lags.

So, on Android I have the problem that I have a black-grey-faded screen before I start my app. I searched on stackoverflow and googled a lot to fix this, but the answers out there wasn't helping.

I've readed that this screen is a standard Android Theme and could changed by following code:

```
<config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="merge">
 <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"> 
 </application>
</config-file>
```

After this didn't worked another user tells, that when PGB CLI-6.5.0 used you have to change it to this:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="merge">
 <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"> 
 </application>
</gap:config-file>
```

Even this is not working for me.

Actually, this is my config.xml:

```css
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="xxx" version="0.1.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <name>testify</name>
  <description>
    There's no need for descriptions. This app is just simple and beautiful.
  </description>
  <author email="xxx" href="xxx">
    Lupoly
  </author>
  <content src="index.html" />

 <!-- Plugin Liste -->
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.2" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-audiotoggle" spec="1.0.3" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-headsetdetection" spec="3.0.0" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" spec="2.31.5"  />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="2.0.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />

 <!-- Allgemeine Einstellungen -->
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
 <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
 <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />

  <!-- splashscreen Einstellungen -->
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />

 <!-- Links -->
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
      <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
      <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
      <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>

 <platform name="android">
  <!-- Androideinstellungen -->
    <config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="merge">
        <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"></application>
    </config-file>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
  <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="27" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="12" />
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="Internal" />

  <!-- Android Icons -->
  <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
  <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
  <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
  <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
  <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
  <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
 </platform>


  <!-- iOS Lokalisierungssprache -->
  <config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion" overwrite="true">
    <string>German</string>
  </config-file>

 <platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS Sound Permission Request -->
    <feature name="Media">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSound" />
    </feature>
    <preference platform="ios" name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
    <preference platform="ios" name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>
    <preference platform="ios" name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />

  <!-- Overscroll wird deaktiviert -->
  <preference platform="ios" name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
  <preference platform="ios" name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference platform="ios" name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />

  <!-- Fullscreen wird auf iOS7 deaktiviert -->
  <preference platform="ios" name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />

  <!-- iOS Einstellungen -->
  <preference name="target-device" value="handset" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="false" />
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />
  <preference name="deployment-target" value="8.0" />

  <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
  <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
  <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
  <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
  <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
  <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
  <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
  <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
  <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
  <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
  <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
  <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
  <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
  <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
  <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
  <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
 </platform>



  <!-- Splashscreens -->
  <platform name="android">
   <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
   <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
   <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
   <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
   <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
   <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
   <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
   <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
   <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
   <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
   <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
   <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
   <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
   <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
   <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
   <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
   <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
   <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
   <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
   <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
   <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
   <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
   <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
   <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
   <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
   <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
   <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
   <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
   <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
   <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
   <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
   <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
   <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
  </platform>

</widget>
```

I hope you guys can help to solve the problem. :)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8iNJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but that should be common to every Android app. It's kind a loading screen that disappear when the app is ready